# background notification : android

Tags: java, android, mobile, notifications

I am new to Android development.
I want to show user notification even when the app is not open.
something like background notification.
It will listen to a server and will retrieve updates from every 30 minutes and will show
the user the message. How can I implement this on android.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use background/foreground [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in order to obtain this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against status bar notifications.  I'm guessing a home screen widget is closer to what you want.  If you know the data is likely to change inside your 30-minute update window, then use the alarm manager to wake your application and refresh the display.  If the data feed changes unpredictably, then use cloud-to-device messaging to tell your application when to update.

Comment: I couldnt get colud-to-device messaging, sorry. Couild u explain it more. thank you

Comment: I couldnt get colud-to-device messaging, sorry. Couild u explain it more. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [status bar notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) or [toast notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the basics of android development. Tyr reading [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) which will help you how to do a service which will work in background. After you understand this it'll be easy for you to add notification from your Service. Good luck.